# Using the contains() method

Tags: vba, visual-studio

Hello I am trying trying to use the contains method to see if a list-block (which exclusively consists of filepaths) 'contains' a certain string. It is supposed to remove the respective entry (in a for loop) if the string is contained in the filepath.

```
    Dim index As Integer = findNumFiles("Archer", 6) '//returns number of files in archer directory
    Dim iString As String = "Archer"



    For i = 0 To index
    If Lookup.Items(index).contains(iString) Then
        removeFromList(Lookup, index) '//passes "Lookup" as a ListBlock name and removes the index number
    End If
    Next
```

a sample filepath would be

```
"Z:\Movies and TV\Archer\Season 6\1.mp4"
```

edit: I forgot to mention that it does not work. I tested the command with a list entry simply named "archer" and if the iString is = to "archer", that list entry is removed. It seems the fact that I'm attempting to use the contains method on a filepath is the problem but I'm not sure. 
Thanks for any insight!

Comment: is it normal to not use i within the loop body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Instr function to check if the string present or not,
I am not sure about what "Lookup.Items" .
Use 'i'in for loop instead of index

Hope below code will help you

```
Sub test1()

Dim index  As Integer

    index = findNumFiles("Archer", 6)

'//returns number of files in archer directory

    Dim iString As String
    iString = "Archer"

    For i = 0 To index
        If InStr(1,Lookup.Items(i), iString, 1) > 0 Then
          ' removeFromList(Lookup, index) '//passes "Lookup" as a ListBlock name and removes the index number
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```